# Create android app programmatically with java code

Tags: java, android, compilation, libgdx

I am new to java and Andriod development I just want to ask if it's possible to compile android app with java code without the need for android studio.
I want to develop an app that generates android source code and compiles it into .apk.

sorry if my English is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute all the build tasks available to your Android project using the Gradle wrapper command line tool.

You can find more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Comment: is it possible to do it on an android app

Comment: Yes, you can try it